# Esperantlingva vorto por "beef jerky"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Ĉu mi simple uzu "striojn de sekigita bovaĵo" aŭ ekzistas apartan vorton por ĉi tiu frandaĵo?

("Google Translate" neniam malsukcesas amuzi en tiaj situacioj. Laŭ ĝi:

"jerky" = "ŝerca"
"beef jerky" = "bovaĵo ŝika"

Ĉu iu ajn iam opiniis ke tiu manĝaĵo estas *ŝika*?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via traduko bonas. Kaj mi tuj komprenis. Mi tamen ŝatus proponi aliajn eblojn:

Mi konsiderus ankaŭ *tranĉaĵo* (mi pensas pri la modelo *pantranĉo* aŭ tranĉaĵoj de ŝinko_  ekzemple, kiu estas en Tekstaro.com):

```
tranĉaĵoj de sekigita bovaĵo
```

Se vi ne devas mencii ke temas pri pecoj (ĉu tranĉoj, ĉu strioj) vi povas aldoni iom da informo (salo) kaj paroli pri:

```
sekigita sala bovaĵo
```

aŭ pli mallonge:

```
bovaĵa salaĵo

vianda salaĵo
```

Ĉar oni nun faras tion plejofte el bovina viando, sed povus esti iu ajn viando. Kaj [*salaĵo*](http://vortaro.net/#sala%C4%B5o) estas "Nutraĵo, salita por konservado".

Comment: Mi konsentas, kaj uzos "bovaĵan salaĵon" en mia traduko. Se oni devas priskribi la formon de la manĝaĵo eblas diri "strioj/tranĉaĵoj de bovaĵa salaĵo". Same kiel en la angla oni kutime diras "strips of beef jerky". Dankon!